# jQuery load() certain div or id that is inside a php file?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, templates, load, loading

I want to load (refresh a part) of my page if I click on a button. Therefore I am using this `jQuery` code in `Wordpress`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#dynamic").load("single.php");
});
```

What I want is to load a certain div or ID that is in the file in single.php, but I can't get it to work. I tried this, but it did not work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#dynamic").load("single.php + '#certain-id'");
});
```

Is the thing I ask even possible with jQuery? If yes, how? I just want an Ajax like refresh of my posts...

PS: I am using single.php, so each post has an unique `URL` name. Therefore I can't use the `hyperlink` in the function. **So in a nutshell: I don't want to load the whole single.php, but a part of single.php.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give `selector` in [load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748013/jquery-load-certain-div-or-id-that-is-inside-a-php-file/17748041#17748041), after the file you are loading

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#dynamic").load("single.php #certain-id");
});
```

#### Loading Page Fragments

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
> the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
> syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
> included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
> space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
> to be loaded.
>
> We could modify the example above to use only part of the document
> that is fetched:
>
> 1 $('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
>
> When this method
> executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html, but then jQuery
> parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of
> container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the
> element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved document
> is discarded, [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: Shoot, I was close. Damn, thanks mate! The problem now is that I am getting this new content in the already existing content. Do I have to use `remove()` or something in jQuery to replace the existing div?

Comment: You were close enough and that really good impression :), Try jQuery("#dynamic").html(""); before load.

Comment: It says: `.html.load is not a function`